# Prove that a triangle is isosceles

Tags: geometry

[image]

Point E is on AC,point D is on BC

CD=AE,∠DAC=∠ABE,∠C=2∠ABE.

Prove:AB=AC

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried and what did / didn't work?

Comment: is D mid point of BC and E mid point of AC

Comment: I cant see the information on the corner of image can you share it with us please

Comment: @Jam the problem doesn't say D and E are mid points.

Comment: @Jam the words in the image is the problem.I have translated the problem into English.

Comment: there is a perpendicular sign there so i am a little confused by

Comment: @T.Bongers I tried to draw a circle to use the angles,made some isosceles triangles in the picture.But I can't prove AB=AC...

Comment: Where is the perpendicular sign??

Comment: Are you sure it is a "perpendicular" sign?  Or some Chinese character, with an extra little segment to the right...

Comment: That is a sign meaning angle.∠A means Angle A

Comment: ok then for AB=AC angle B= angle C try some angle woking for example call angle DAC=X then angle C=2X

Comment: I confirm that the translation is exact and correct. The funny looking symbol '上' means "on" in Chinese. It is definitely not '┴'.